# How to allow only com and net domain name in regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am using regular expressions to validate emails in PHP. I want to allow only `.com`, or `.net` domain names. How can I achieve this?

**My code:**

```
<?php
    $my_email = "name@company.com"

    if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/", $my_email)) {
        echo "$my_email is a valid email address";
    } else {
        echo "$my_email is NOT a valid email address";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex for this.  The safest/simplest way is using php's filter_var() function and a check on the last four characters without regex.

```
if (filter_var($my_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && in_array(substr($my_email, -4),['.com','.net'])) {
    echo "valid email"; 
}else{
    echo "invalid email";
}
```

Sorry I could not test this code because my phone crashes when I try to use php sandbox.  (It may have a syntax error -- but the principle is here.)